# Update/Create Mutation with Django Graphene

Tags: python, django, django-models, graphql, graphene-python

I'm struggling to find a good example or best practice to create an elegant way for update/create mutations for related models with django and graphene.

Let say you have a model Address with OneToOne relation with (City, State, Zipcode)

```
class ZipCode(models.Model):
    zip = models.IntegerField(_("Zip"), blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.zip

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('Zip codes')


class State(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(_("State"), max_length=12, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('States')


class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=12, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('Cities')


class Address(models.Model):
    line_1 = models.CharField(_("Address Line 1"), max_length=256, blank=True)
    line_2 = models.CharField(_("Address Line 2"), max_length=256, blank=True)
    state = models.OneToOneField(
        State,
        related_name=_("address_state"),
        verbose_name=_("State"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    city = models.OneToOneField(
        City,
        related_name=_("address_city"),
        verbose_name=_("City"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    zipcode = models.OneToOneField(
        ZipCode,
        related_name=_("address_zipcode"),
        verbose_name=_("ZipCode"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        verbose_name_plural = _("Addresses")
```

How would you create a mutation in a elegant way that can accept query like:

```
mutation {
  updateAddress(addressData: {line_1: "Test"}, zipData: { zip: "12345" }, cityData: {city: "New York"}, stateData: { state: "NY" }) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi, how about using serializers like here so: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers and then using serializers mutations, as in graphene-django, or this library https://github.com/topletal/django-model-mutations . Only difference I would probably suggest is make the zipData, cityData etc nested to address data, so it works nicely in the serializer - same as shown in the example in the rest-serializer documentation I linked

Comment: @Marko Did you find out the best practice?